# How do I remove the displayed "1.2.11.2.1" in the compiled document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone, import

I am writing a handout using the `report` class in Overleaf. I wanted to add a graph I had made beforehand in another document (named fig 1.2.1) and I uploaded it to `main.tex`. I used `import` and this happened.

[image: Text]

This is my code at around that point:

```
We call set $C$ the graph of the function $y=f(x)$. The figure below is a graph of the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined over all real numbers.

\import{figures/}{fig 1.2.1}
```

This is my code for `fig 1.2.1.tex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,backgrounds,fit}  

%pgflots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}


%colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    trig format =  rad,
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = none, 
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard, width=10cm, height=8cm,
                xtick={\empty},
                ytick={\empty},
                xticklabels={\empty},
                yticklabels={\empty},
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                samples=1000,
                xmin=-3, xmax=3,
                ymin=-1, ymax=2]
        \node[anchor=center,label=south west:O] at (axis cs:0.12,0.07){};
        \coordinate (start_y) at (axis cs:0,-0.15); %y axis
        \coordinate (end_y)   at (axis cs:0,1.5);
        \node[anchor=center,label=$y$] at (axis cs:0.175,1.44) {};
        \draw[-stealth] (start_y) -- (end_y);

        
        \addplot[domain={-2.1:2.1}]{0.3*x^2};
            \draw (0.8,1.3) node [draw = rectangle, rounded corners] {\small Ran$(f)$};
            \node (A) at (0.511,1.258) {};
            \draw[-stealth](A) to [out=-2.4,in=0.1] (0,1.1);

            \node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (-1.632, 0.8) {};
            \filldraw [black] (B) circle (1pt) node[left] {point $(x,y)$};
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (Bx) at (-1.632, 0) {};
            \node[inner sep=1pt] (By) at (0, 0.8) {};
            \filldraw [black] (Bx) circle (1pt) node[below] {$x$};
            \filldraw [black] (By) circle (1pt) node[right] {$x^2$};

            \node[inner sep=0pt] (C) at (1.3662, 0.56) {};
            \filldraw [black] (C) circle (1pt) node[right] {point $(x,y)$};
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (Cx) at (1.3662, 0) {};
            \node[inner sep=1pt] (Cy) at (0, 0.56) {};
            \filldraw [black] (Cx) circle (1pt) node[below] {$x$};
            \filldraw [black] (Cy) circle (1pt) node[left] {$x^2$};

            \draw[-stealth] (Bx)--(B) node [midway, left] {$f$} ->(By) node [midway, above] {$f$} ;
            \draw[-stealth] (Cx)--(C) node [midway, left] {$f$} ->(Cy) node [midway, above] {$f$};

            \draw (1.5,-0.3) node [draw = rectangle, rounded corners] {\small Dom$(f)=\mathbb{R}\; (\text{all real numbers})$};
            \draw[-stealth] (1.95,-0.2) -- (2,0);

            \node[right] at (1.65, 0.8) {$y=f(x)$};

            \draw (2.5,1.05) node [draw = rectangle, rounded corners] {\small graph $C$};
            \draw[-stealth] (2.075,1.05)--(1.871,1.05);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The 1.2.11.2.1 appeared before the graph, and I cannot find a way to erase it.

I'm sorry if my code bothers you in any way. Since I have only recently started to explore the world of `TikZ` and `pgfplots`, any suggestions and corrections towards my code is very much appreciated.

additional info:
my packages for `main.tex`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,backgrounds,fit}  
%pgflots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
%colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

%format
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setlength\parindent{10pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{float}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't quite work as is, I think :) First of all, in the figure you have `draw=rectangle`, which is wrong. The argument to `draw` should be a color name, if you want to specify the shape do `draw, rectangle`. However, `rectangle` is the default, so you can do just `draw`, if you haven't changed the default.

Second, I had to add `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}` in `main.tex` as well.

That said, it looks like `import` doesn't like spaces in the filename, if I rename the file to `fig1.2.1.tex` and change `main.tex` correspondingly, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your advice.